# openbsd httpd with gunicorn+uvicorn -- Remote protocol error : illegal request line

Tags: python, gunicorn, httpd.conf, uvicorn, openbsd

My web deployment setup is on openBSD and consists of httpd  on front with  guicorn + uvicorn as the back engine, connected  via unix socket.

The setup works, in the sense that requests from httpd are being forwarded to gunicorn over the unix sockets. However, the gunicorn/uvicorn is not able to understand the incoming http request.
The error stack

```
[2021-11-22 22:52:17 +0530] [1631] [WARNING] Invalid HTTP request received.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shared/Builds/Python-3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 136, in handle_events
    event = self.conn.next_event()
  File "/home/shared/Builds/Python-3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 443, in next_event
    exc._reraise_as_remote_protocol_error()
  File "/home/shared/Builds/Python-3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h11/_util.py", line 76, in _reraise_as_remote_protocol_error
    raise self
  File "/home/shared/Builds/Python-3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 425, in next_event
    event = self._extract_next_receive_event()
  File "/home/shared/Builds/Python-3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 367, in _extract_next_receive_event
    event = self._reader(self._receive_buffer)
  File "/home/shared/Builds/Python-3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h11/_readers.py", line 68, in maybe_read_from_IDLE_client
    raise LocalProtocolError("illegal request line")
h11._util.RemoteProtocolError: illegal request line
```

I am not sure what are potential causes for illegal request line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`httpd` is not support http proxying.
It is support serving static files as well as `FastCGI`. And error message, indicate that your `httpd` try to communicate with gunicorn using `FastCGI`.

So, if you stick to `httpd`, find a way to run your app using `FastCGI` server instead of `WSGI` (`gunicorn`). Many years ago `flup` was a popular choice.

Or, just use `Nginx` instead of `httpd`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. There is a documentation for uWSGI connecting to httpd (https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/OpenBSDhttpd.html) which I think is a WSGI so I  had presumed gunicorn would work as well.